# AngularJS - ui - carousel

Tags: html, angularjs

Пытаюсь реализовать карусель на ангулахJS. Но что-то идет не так. Юзаю пример по это ссылке. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-carousel

Устанавливаю дериктивы таким образом

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/angular-ui-carousel@0.1.10/dist/ui-carousel.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/angular-ui-carousel@0.1.10/dist/ui-carousel.min.css" integrity="sha256-EBvZV6QlRzFD0ZxEjZ7f0bV7eyyM+JNuYP3Fq1f00+o=" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Ссылки беру вот 
[тут](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/angular-ui-carousel?path=dist)
Как я понимаю так тоже можно, не обязательно ж нпм или галп

В итоге я собираю как в инструкции

```
(function (angular) {
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.carousel']);
})(window.angular);
```

app.run

```
(function (angular) {
angular.module('app').run(runFn);

runFn.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'Carousel', '$transitions', '$location', 'authService'];

function runFn($rootScope, Carousel, $transitions, $location, authSevice) {
    Carousel.setOptions({
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        cssEase: 'ease',
        dots: false,

        easing: 'linear',
        fade: false,
        infinite: true,
        initialSlide: 0,

        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        speed: 500,
      });
```

Ну и HTML

```
 <ui-carousel slides="ctrl.fade.slides" slides-to-show="3" slides-to-scroll="1">
    <carousel-item>
        <div class="image"><img src="/Content/FilesBlog/27.01.2019/93/1.png"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="/Content/FilesBlog/27.01.2019/93/2.png"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="/Content/FilesBlog/27.01.2019/93/3.png"></div>
    </carousel-item>
</ui-carousel>
```

И по факту на HTML просто пусто!..директива никак не реагирует. Как заставить ее работать? Может у кого то есть адекватный короткий вариант?

Comment: runFn срабатывает? лог добавляли? или бряку

Comment: Работает отлично..так как там ниже при смене страницы работает проверка на авторизацию.